# create a function like SimpleDateFormat in Java using Common Lisp

Tags: date, common-lisp

I found there are not powerful tool like Java `SimpleDateFormat` in common lisp.

It is too difficult for me to understand the principle of the `SimpleDateFormat`, so I have to 
write by myself . And I wrote a function 'date-formatter' but i think it is too ugly and exists some bugs .

Can you explain how the `SimpleDateFormat` realize or provide the powerful function

```
(defparameter *pattern-char* "yMdhHmsS")
```

Function `DATE-FORMATTER`:

```
(defun date-formatter (pattern str)
  (let ((year nil)
        (month nil)
        (day nil)
        (hour nil)
        (minite nil)
        (second nil)
        (index nil))
    (do* ((index 0 (+ 1 index))
          (c (subseq *pattern-char* index (+ 1 index))
             (subseq *pattern-char* index (1+ index)))
          (p  (concatenate 'string c "+")
              (concatenate 'string c "+"))
          (m (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings p pattern)
             (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings p pattern)))
         ((= index (1- (length *pattern-char*))))
      (if m
          (let* ((i (subseq str (search m pattern)
                            (+ (length m) (search m pattern)))))
            (cond ((< 0 (length (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings "y+" m)))
                   (setf year (parse-integer i)))
                  ((< 0 (length (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings "M*" m)))
                   (setf month (parse-integer i)))
                  ((< 0 (length (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings "d*" m)))
                   (setf day (parse-integer i)))
                  ((< 0 (length (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings "H*" m)))
                   (setf hour (parse-integer i)))
                  ((< 0 (length (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings "m*" m)))
                   (setf minite (parse-integer i)))
                  ((< 0 (length (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings "s*" m)))
                   (setf second (parse-integer i)))
                  (t (print "error!!"))))))
    (values year month day hour minite second)))
```

Example:

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 0) (safety 3) (debug 3)))

(defun f ()
  (multiple-value-bind (year month day hour minute second)
      (date-formatter "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" "2013-05-12 23:22:11")
    (list year month day hour minute second )))
```

Comment: You will have to be more specific about your question.  What is the problem here and what is not working?

Comment: That is not a date-formatter but a date-parser.

Answer (score 4):

[local-time](http://common-lisp.net/project/local-time/) is a library for dates and times, the doco is [here](http://common-lisp.net/project/local-time/manual.html) and was being actively developed as recently as 2 months ago.

You can install it by typing (ql:quickload :local-time) in your lisp shell and hitting return (assuming you have quicklisp installed)

It is the 3rd result in the google search "common lisp dates and times" and the first was [this link to the common lisp cookbook page on dates & times](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/dates_and_times.html)

Hope they help!

**[EDIT]**

More info! The library is pretty cool so I though I would just post this addendum:

local-time:parse-timestring is nice as you can specify exactly how the datetime string is laid out. By default it expects that the date-seperator is #\- and the time-seperator is #\: which are both correct (remember that #\ is used to specify a character), however I had to set date-time-seperator to be #\space as my input has a space between the date and time. See below!.

```
CL-USER> (local-time:parse-timestring "2013-01-23 12:12:12" :date-time-separator #\space) 
 @2013-01-23T12:12:12.000000Z
```